# Excel - List all values for column A where the corresponding value in column B is blank

Tags: excel, ms-office

In Microsoft Excel I want to create a column that lists all of the values from column A, where the corresponding field in column B of the same row is blank (eg. where cell B2 is blank, I want to display the contents of cell A2).

I don't want to display any cells from column A where the corresponding cell in column B of the same row is not blank (eg. where cell B3 is not blank, don't display cell A3, or any value at all)

The data might look like this:

```
A   B
--- ---
123 
234 345
456 456
567
```

What I want to display is a new column with only the values from column A where column B in the same row is blank, like this, so all I would see from the above is:

```
C
---
123
567
```

I tried this:

```
=IF(B2="",A2)
```

However the above displays a value of "FALSE" wherever column B is blank, like this:

```
C
--------
123
FALSE
FALSE
567
```

Is there a way I can do what I'm asking above?

Comment: Probably the simplest way is to set up an **AutoFilter** on column **B**.

Comment: You could fix your formula to show nothing, instead of FALSE with `=IF(B2="",A2,"")`. That will still show the blank rows though. @Gary'sStudent has a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$4;SMALL(IF(TRIM($B$1:$B$4)="";ROW($A$1:$A$4)-ROW($A$1)+1;"");ROW(A1)))
```

I assume, in this case values in A1:B4
Dont forget it is an array formula so Ctrl Shift Enter to enter the formula.

Write the formula wherever you want and then copy down to get next values

Depending on your Regional Settings you may need to replace field separator ";" by ","

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately it's not working (in Excel 2010).  I did have to change it to "," instead of ";" to stop getting a pop-up error, but now it's just displaying "#NUM!".  Possibly my examples are misleading.  The cells actually contain text, not numbers.  I'm not sure if that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: It must work with any kind of data, and I said that eventually you need to replace ";". Did you Ctrl Shift Enter to enter the formula?